# Why do i get Error when i try to run or start my win service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service which i can't run or start, only install or directly debug the project.

This is my main:

```
namespace MyService
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new Service() };
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Service:

```
public partial class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        private dynamic _serviceHost;

        public Service()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.ServiceName = "MyService";
            this.CanShutdown = true;
            this.CanStop = true;
        }

        private static string HostName
        {
            get
            {
                string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                IPHostEntry ipHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
                return ipHostEntry.HostName;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            var worker = new Thread(this.InitializeHost) { Name = "Host", IsBackground = false };
            worker.Start();
        }

        private void InitializeHost()
        {
            var baseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}:{1}/MyService", HostName, "9020"));
            var mexAddress = new Uri(string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/MyService", HostName, "8000"));
            var cache = Factory.Create<string>("MyAssembly.MyClass", "MyAssembly");
            var service = new ServiceWcf<string>(cache);
            using (this._serviceHost = new Host<string>(service))
            {
                this._serviceHost.Open(baseAddress, mexAddress);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            this._serviceHost.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

When I try to run without debugging or to start after installing the service i get the following error:

Run (directly or through VS):
Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program
'C:\path\to\my\projects\bin\Release\MyService.exe'.
The system cannot find the specified path.

Service start:
The service "MyService" on local cimpouter could not be started.
Error 3: The system cannot find the specified path.

I have no clue where the error could be.

EDIT:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.serviceProcessInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
            this.serviceInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
            // 
            // serviceProcessInstaller
            // 
            this.serviceProcessInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;
            this.serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
            // 
            // serviceInstaller
            // 
            this.serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "MyService";
            this.serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "My service";
            this.serviceInstaller.Description = "My service is awesome.";
            this.serviceInstaller.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            // 
            // ProjectInstaller
            // 
            this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
            this.serviceProcessInstaller,
            this.serviceInstaller});

        }
```

Comment: perhaps there is something wrong with the service registration? can you show us how you do  that?

Comment: Is there a file missing from the 'Release' folder that is present in the 'Debug' folder?

Comment: no, both outputs are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just an issue with how the service has been registered - i.e. it's in the wrong place.

run an `installutil /u [service]` from a VS command prompt to uninstall any service entries you already have.

CD over to the folder where you want to run the service from - **be careful here**, you will have both a debug and a release build - which one do you want to be installed in the services list?

Use `installutil /i [service]` on the exe to reinstall.

Now it should work.

I think you might have registered the debug build first and have subsequently run a Clean operation on the build before building the Release version; thus deleting the original executable.  Either that - or perhaps you moved the project after originally developing it?

Many of the developers I work with use a different folder for their local service installations that is always the same; they then deploy either a debug or release version to it; thus when they want to switch between the two they just copy different file versions over.  I don't do this - I only ever register the debug build; but then I have more work to do when testing the release build :)

Comment: okay i have run installutil /u on both builds of the service (debug/release) cleaned the output build and rebuild release. it still throws this error.

Comment: @mrt181 - please verify from the services MMC snap-in that the path is correct. Or download psservice (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897542.aspx) and query it using psservice config [service_name].  The error message, to me, is saying that the executable is not where it thinks it is.

Comment: the path to the executable is correct. i also get the error when i try to run the executable manually.

Comment: @mrt181: Okay, so if it *really* isn't that; then it must be something to do with that service host.  Take out the code that opens the service host (perhaps just don't open the thread), rebuild and redeploy then see if the same thing happens.  If it does, then it must still be the installation path or something like it because the service is now not doing anything :)

Comment: i have commented both lines in OnStart(), the method does nothing now. I still get this error when i try to run or start the executable

Comment: It has something to do with the executables name. The name is the same as the namespace and assemblyname + exe. The moment i deviate from this the executable starts!?!? why does it behave like this?

Comment: @mrt181 - that's interesting; assuming it's installing correctly (which apparently it is) then I'm thinking it's something to do with the service runner not being able to locate the service entry point of the executable due to naming.  Would have to setup a test project for this

Comment: @mrt181 - I just created a service whose service name is MyService, the component is MyService, in the namespace MyService, and the executable name is MyService.MyService.exe - all works fine.

Comment: strange. maybe it also has something to do with the length of the name. I have to use this project, namespace and assembly name (obfuscated the real name but the length is the same): 
ABCDE.Subabcd.ApplicationName1.MyMyMService

Comment: @mrt181: ah - could you be hitting the max path limit of 260 characters? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths

Comment: no. i used the PathScan v0.11 tool to look at the path lenghts. my fully named exe would have a path lenght of 157 characters.

Comment: @mrt181 - well, in that case, I'm all out of ideas! :(